# ListView in Objective-C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I used for some time the .net framework, especially Wpf. Now I need to develop an application for Os X using cocoa. In wpf I have the ListView object where each element can be what object I want. I need to use an alternative in cocoa that allows me to scroll I list of personal "user control".

Is there such alternative?

Comment: In recent versions os OS X, you can us "view-based" NSTableView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alternative of List-view in OS X is TableView, you can refer to the Apple documentation for the reference.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView

Comment: The view based NSTableView is definitely a good solution here. It is actually MUCH easier than custom cell based table views, but still means you will need to learn a bit about how views work in Cocoa and how table views work as well in order to succeed. It's doable, but if you are new to cocoa, it's a lot of stuff at once, with a lot of prerequisites. You will definitely need to learn about delegates, data sources and formal protocols to put this all together. Once you get those, it will become very easy.